# `bundle update rails` takes hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I have been trying to update my Rails app from `3.2.11` to `3.2.13` by changing my `Gemfile` and running `bundle update rails`.

This is what happened:

```
Updating git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

It has been going on for over an hour and there are well over a thousand dots.

Is it safe to stop this process and try again? How can I resolve this?

Comment: do a `gem install rails -v 3.2.13`. And after that remove your `Gemfile.lock` and then do a `bundle install`.

Comment: @stevanity I stopped the process and did what you suggested. Now that I ran `bundle install`, I'm into the first few hundred dots and it's still going.

Comment: `DEBUG_RESOLVER=1 bundle install` try this. We'l get an idea as to  whats causing the issue.

Comment: Please show us your `Gemfile`.

Comment: @stevanity Using `DEBUG_RESOLVER=1 bundle install` I managed to debug and fix the issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution after running `DEBUG_RESOLVER=1 bundle install`.

There was a circularity going on where Rails would begin at v 3.2.13, then it would be changed to 3.2.14 to resolve a dependency, then it would be changed back on the next pass. So, it seems all that time it was toggling back and forth.

I manually changed the versions in my Gemfile to eliminate the circularity that I saw in the logs, and that ended up fixing the issue.